# Publishin data from sql server in web

Tags: sql-server, xml, iis-7, publishing

I'm developing small application for my colleagues, I have some procedure on SQL Server, which returns XML. And I'd like to publish this XML on the Web server.

I think that should exist easy way to do it, but I can find it.

I have the following setup:

- SQL Server 2005 Standard
- IIS 7
- Windows Server 2008

best regards

Comment: Does exists any other way without ASP? My be some kind SOAP  technology. But when i use it, have extra tags, witch useless for me.

Answer (score 0):

create ASP.Net page that gets results from SQL Server. http://www.asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following options

- Display raw XML on the web site.
- Display the XML in an ASP.Net page
- Display the XML data in a data grid
- Apply a style sheet and display the XML data